# Visualize countplot like linegraph python

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a data frame for customer transactions:

```
     customer_id|tier |transaction_type|year|no_of_purchases
       1353455  |1    |online          |2012|5
       1353455  |1    |retail          |2012|8
       1353455  |1    |retail          |2014|10
       1543798  |2    |retail          |2012|1
```

The tier is their loyalty program tier. I want to see if there is difference in the transaction_type and no_of_purchases between each tier.

I did a countplot for this:

`sns.countplot(x="transaction_type", y="no_of_purchase", hue"tier")`

**Goal**: I want show for each year (x-axis) what is the count of the no_purchases for each transaction_type and how does this differ for each tier. Here is an example of how I want it to look. Ideally we would have 4 graphs, one for each of the transaction type. It would be great if we can show the count at each point too.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use seaborn [catplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html).

First, you can aggregate your data, then do the vizualization using seaborn.

```
data_viz = df.groupby(['year','transaction_type','tier'], as_index=False)['no_of_purchases'].sum()

sns.catplot(data=data_viz, x='year', y='no_of_purchases', hue='tier', col='transaction_type', kind='bar')
```

But unfortunately based on the documentation, you cannot plot the data using line plot.

---

There is a work around though, you can do something like this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_viz = df.groupby(['year','transaction_type','tier'], as_index=False)['no_of_purchases'].sum()

for i in list(data_viz['transaction_type'].unique()):
    viz = sns.lineplot(data=data_viz[data_viz['transaction_type'] == i], x='year', y='no_of_purchases', hue='tier')
    plt.title(i)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way I can add annotations to each graph at the end of the line? To make it easier to read?

Comment: I'm not sure but you can check in the matplotlib doumentation -> https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/annotations.html